# Separate string after equal number of characters with white space

Tags: php

basically what I need is to convert 
 
123456789012345678901234567 
 to  
 12345 67890 12345 67890 12345 67
 
 
So after each 5th element a white space is inserted. I can do it in old fashioned ways but was wondering if there is a quick alternative.

Comment: in my case string was small and its length was constant and I only had to split in 2 places. So I was doing it manually like 
$arr = str_split($text, "5");
$newtext = $arr['0'].' '.$arr['1'].' '.$arr['2']; 
But was interested in general what is the best way of doing it if the string length is not constant. Now there are some good answers already posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$text = "123456789012345678901234567";

$newtext = wordwrap($text, 5, "\n", true);

echo $newtext;

Comment: just need a white space instead of \n ! Thnx

Answer (score 2):

```
echo join(' ', str_split('123456789012345678901234567', 5));
```

Comment: Why not user **`implode()`** instead of **`join()`** ?

Comment: *Why* use `implode` instead of `join`? They're the same thing.

Comment: join is an alias for implode :)